# Will the winter bash hats be available for download after January?

Tags: support, winter-bash

If let's say we're really proud of a hat, I wanted to ask if we'll be able to download that hat and then add it into our profile picture and re-upload it to keep it all year around.

Therefore, I wanted to ask: Will all the available hats (existing and hidden) be either available for download or displayed once the winter bash is over?

Or will the secret hats stay secret (Even tough it would be awesome to see all of them)

Comment: Nice how answering this question or voting for it gets you a hat today :)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

On [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245170/winter-bash-2014-secret-hats) there will be a concluding post, revealing all the secrets and the exact rules for the hats. To reach a broader audience [there is also a blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/winter-bash-2013-wrap-up/).

The Winterbash site normally stays live throughout the year. The 2014 results were live till October, 29th based on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270397/158100) from [balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha).

By some reverse engineering you can preserve all hats.

- [2014](https://jsfiddle.net/9grzgxwy/)
- [2015](http://jsfiddle.net/vj3wpmea/1/) (kindly provided by [@Doorhandle](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4362822#4362822))

Comment: 2015 is missing the Flip Flop hat.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Yeah, the secret hats are somewhat difficult this year, I'll check if I can add them somehow.

Comment: HOW TO GET THE 4th DOCTOR HAT! *cough* *scurries off to google*

Comment: You front end/full stackers with your trickses... Cool!

Answer (score 10):

[Here're the *found* secret hats of 2015](https://jsfiddle.net/pb2p32th/) (with the ids they would have if they wouldn't be secret).

I'd obviously would embed them right there with the Stack Snippet, but the body is limited to 30,000 chars, while the snippet length is about 50,000 chars.

Comment: Good to know that you also hit the 30,000 limit ... done that, been there...