# Are hats permanent in the profile?

Tags: support, winter-bash

Will the hats be taken back from the profile once the 
Winter Bash is over? Or are the hats memoirs that we can take permanently?

I really liked some hats which could nicely be integrated to my profile picture.

Comment: They'll be..as ernie harwell used to say...LONG GONNNNNNNNNE..

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/winterbash-2015/info - "Unlike badges, hats are temporary."

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313127/will-the-winter-bash-hats-be-available-for-download-after-january

Comment: You could take a screenshot of your avatar with the hat on it and turn that into your new avatar. Only works for hats that don't leak outside the avatar borders, of course.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Winter Bash hats are meant as an event for the end of the year on the Gregorian calendar. It also serves as experiment for new badges and how to foment some behavior. So, no, hats will go away when the event ends.

Comment: but they should remain i thinik so

Comment: @ImranQamer Its nice to want things :)

Answer (score 10):

They are not permanent, for a source, see the main Winter Bash front page:

> the hats get put back in their boxes on January 4th!

- http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Too bad, it would be funny to wear them longer :-(

Comment: @rekire: Just capture your avatar with your favorite hat. That's also the way to wear multiple hats...

Answer (score 3):

Its mention on main page like :

```
    Stack Exchange invites you to celebrate the end of a great year …with
 HATS! As you use your site, you'll discover hats and other items hidden
 behind certain actions. Collect all of them, some of them, or none of them,
 but be quick – the hats get put back in their boxes on January 4th!
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope sorry bud. The winter bash has been going for some years and after a period of time the functionality is turned off and the hats go away.

If your keen try screen dump and an image editor

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could always photoshop/gimp your picture, adding your favorite hat/mask on top of it. (one difference: the hat/mask may be a bit larger than the picture - which effect cannot be rendered on the picture only, obviously )

Comment: Or use Paint for MS fans and play around with the image editing functionality :) Simple :)