# Is there a way to save hats for history?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

I plan to spend some time and earn some hats. But I did not find any options to save them. It seems that all progress will be lost, as the pages for [2014](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/) and [2015](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/) no longer show any hats.

I think it would be a good idea to save hats, so I can view them at a later date.

**UPD**
And allow to wear hats only while celebrating is in progress

Comment: Every year this point is made. How can we save our hats? Well, romanticizing them is one way, but really the end of the season is the end of the hats.

Comment: Just save a copy of your profile image and then set that as your new profile image. My profile image is one of the hats form last year

Comment: Use my profile as an example for having multiple hats _and_ saving hats. My previous image used the Vader hat of last year, now I've got the prettier one from this year. :)

Comment: Make a [photo album][1]. That's what we do over on RPG.SE. [1]:http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6640/23970

Comment: Maybe its best to think of it as limited edition

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313127/will-the-winter-bash-hats-be-available-for-download-after-january/313136#313136

Answer (score 37):

Other than grabbing a screenshot on the last day, there's no sure way to keep your hats. I shan't speak for the SE team, but as I understand, this is part of the fun, it's a seasonal fun event, not just another badge system.

Comment: it looks like it is. In other case anybody may just draw he/she want. And there is no any reason to gain any hat.

Answer (score 7):

I'm still waiting for the Unicorns to come back. I saved my unicorn avatar when SO had them back in 2010, and can switch my user icon back to it any time I want.

[image: my unicorn avatar]

By doing a capture of your avatar with the hat you like, you can do the same.

Comment: Also I can draw any avatar I want so It will look like hat. So I no need to earn hat. Just draw...

Comment: @EugenKonkov: Well, I mean… yeah, it's just pixels. You can *pretend* to have the hat, but who are you trying to fool, anyway?

Comment: ssshhh, [here's a hi-res version for you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auaYu.png) (made with https://bitbucket.org/balpha/go-unicornify)