# Do hats persist after the end of the winter bash, or are they temporary?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

Will I be able to continue to display my hat after winterbash2k16 is finished?

Comment: Hats are always [temporary](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/Its-Hat-Season-Announcing-Winter-Bash-2016/?cb=1).

Comment: until 8 january 2017 that's it!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339890/is-there-a-way-to-save-hats-for-history if you want to display your hat

Comment: play tf2 if you want permanent hats.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, at the end of every Winter Bash, they all go back in the box.

> Will I be able to continue to display my hat after winterbash2k16 is finished?

You could take a screenshot.

Comment: screenshot won't do if the hat exceeds the photo's boudaries